# How to get tab object not a active tab object for safari browser?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

How to get tab object dynamically for safari browser.In safari extension api there is method **safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab** this returns current active tab object.

I want tab object for current activetab(solution is there) or deactivetab(how to get deactivetab object).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tab other than the active one, use safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.tabs. This is an array of all the active window's tabs.

safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.tabs[0] is the leftmost tab of the window.

Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SafariExtensionsReference/_index.html).